# How to exclude records satisying two conditions at the same time?

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly complicate query

```
SELECT g.guidUser,u1.username,g.sent,g.accepted,g.declined,g.rewarded,g.guidUserVersus,u2.username AS usernameUserVersus
FROM games g 
INNER JOIN userdata u1 ON g.guidUser=u1.guidUser 
INNER JOIN userdata u2 ON g.guidUserVersus=u2.guidUser 
WHERE 
((g.sent!="" OR g.accepted!="" OR g.declined!="") 
AND g.rewarded="" AND (g.guidUser='1' OR g.guidUserVersus='1')) 
ORDER BY g.guidUser, g.idGame
```

Now I want to exclude records having at the same time

(g.accepted!="" AND g.guidUserVersus='1')

I tried

```
SELECT g.guidUser,u1.username,g.sent,g.accepted,g.declined,g.rewarded,g.guidUserVersus,u2.username AS usernameUserVersus,g.idGameVersus,g.timeFinal 
FROM games g 
INNER JOIN userdata u1 ON g.guidUser=u1.guidUser 
INNER JOIN userdata u2 ON g.guidUserVersus=u2.guidUser 
WHERE 
((g.sent!="" OR g.accepted!="" OR g.declined!="") 
AND g.rewarded="" AND (g.guidUser='1' OR g.guidUserVersus='1')) 
** AND !(g.accepted!="" AND g.guidUserVersus='1') **
ORDER BY g.guidUser, g.idGame
```

But it seems is not selecting records that it should, like having g.accepted!="" AND g.guidUserVersus='2'

Here it is the fiddle
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737e61/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4a917/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: You need to replace AND with OR inside the condition.

```
SELECT g.guidUser,u1.username,g.sent,g.accepted,g.declined,g.rewarded,g.guidUserVersus,u2.username AS usernameUserVersus,g.idGameVersus,g.timeFinal 
FROM games g 
INNER JOIN userdata u1 ON g.guidUser=u1.guidUser 
INNER JOIN userdata u2 ON g.guidUserVersus=u2.guidUser 
WHERE 
((g.sent!="" OR g.accepted!="" OR g.declined!="") 
AND g.rewarded="" AND (g.guidUser='1' OR g.guidUserVersus='1')) 
AND NOT (g.accepted!="" OR g.guidUserVersus='1')
ORDER BY g.guidUser, g.idGame
```

Comment: try it in the fiddle, it still doesn't select the 4' record of games and it should

Comment: The query returns the expected result. The records you want to exclude need to satisfy BOTH the conditions at the same time. Only the second one is satisfied though.

Comment: You need to replace "AND" with "OR". I'll just edit my reply.

Comment: Also, the fourth record is not selected because accepted is not empty, and you are excluding all the records where accepted is not empty.

Comment: whoops, no you were right at the beginning. There was an error in data and the fourth record was not satysfying the condition (g.guidUser='1' OR g.guidUserVersus='1') Thank you!! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b4d0b8/4 Restore AND instead of OR and the answer fits